# How to add a dynamically generated SiteKey(String) to 'SciptManager.RegisterStartupScript'

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, scriptmanager

> I'm using the following script to raise an event in C#:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "Redirect",
"alert('Please Select the right Length!'); window.location='" + Request.ApplicationPath + "/MemberPages/CableData.aspx?SiteKey=';", true);
```

> However, I need to add the following string to the end of the URL: `foo.Site_ID` 
>   which comes from:

```
foo.Site_ID = Request.QueryString["SiteKey"]
```

> So, the URL has to look like this: `"/MemberPages/CableData.aspx?SiteKey=<String>';"`
>   How can I do that, or is there any other script to do it? Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: `+ "/MemberPages/CableData.aspx?SiteKey=" + foo.Site_ID + "';"` ?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can u define - doesn't work? when u debug - does `foo.Site_ID` has a value?

Comment: I does have a value, but it doesn't pass it. It comes up blank. Like: /MemberPages/CableData.aspx?SiteKey=<blank>